# Woocommerce remove link on featured image

Tags: hyperlink, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the link on the featured image when I add a new product in Woocommerce. I did it in the previous version but since updating I can't seem to find how/where I edited it. Trying to look through some files to no avail. Any help?

Answer (score 12):

I originally used css: `pointer-events:none;`

On the link class (I think I used .zoom img) however I needed to use the image for a jQuery zoom so after hours of searching I found this solution, just add this to your functions.php and it will sort you out.

```
/**
  * Remove link wrapping main product image in single product view.
  * @param $html
  * @param $post_id
  * @return string
*/

function custom_unlink_single_product_image( $html, $post_id ) {
    return get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_large_thumbnail_size', 'shop_single' ) );
}

add_filter('woocommerce_single_product_image_html', 'custom_unlink_single_product_image', 10, 2);
```